# How to show the determinant of this $n \times n$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Given $
  A_n =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   2 & 1 & \\
   1 & 2 & 1\\
    & 1 & 2 \\
   & & & ... \\
   & & & & 2 & 1 \\
   & & & & 1 & 2
  \end{array} } \right]
\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$. What I have to do is calculate the determinant with respect to $n\in \mathbb{N}$. I already found out $\det(A_n) = n+1$. I tried to show this with induction. I get confronted by the following problem:

I showed the statement for $n=1$. Lets consider the statement is true for one $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Now show that the statement is also true for $n+1$ using laplace expansion for the first row.

We get $\det(A_{n+1}) = (-1)^2\cdot 2\cdot \det(A_n)+(-1)^3\cdot 1\cdot   
 \begin{vmatrix}
   1 & 1 & \\
   0 & 2 & 1\\
   & 1 & 2 \\
   & & & ... \\
   & & & & 2 & 1 \\
   & & & & 1 & 2
\end{vmatrix}
$. The second determinant should be $1\cdot \det(A_{n-1}) = n$ but we only considered the statement tu be true for $n$ and not for $n-1$. How do I continue from here?

Comment: Use "complete induction". Assume the hypothesis, not just for $n$, but for all of $1,2,\ldots,n$, and then deduce the $n+1$ case.

Comment: I've already thought of that. I was not sure if this is legit to do.

Comment: I know the matrix in the question I marked this one as duplicate of has sub- and sup-diagonal entries $-1$ rather than $1$, but the difference is just a base change where basis vectors $e_i$ are replaced by $(-1)^ie_i$ (conjugation by a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,\ldots$).

Comment: As for the question of strong induction, you can use as induction hypothesis that the statement holds for all $i\leq n$. Since you explicitly need the statement for the last two of these values, you need to prove _two_ initial case separately from the induction argument, so that validity for two previous values is assured even for the first application of the induction step.